# numberOfDigits() in java?

Tags: java, netbeans, recursion

i posted a question similar to this one but I still can't figure how to code this little part. Can someone please tell me how I can add a new method named "numberOfDigits"and a line to test it in the main() method . Below is the code I came up for numberOfZeros. To be more specific, all I want to know is how I can add numberOfDigits to this.

```
import java.util.*;

public class ZeroCounter   {
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         System.out.println("Enter a nonnegative number:");
         Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
         int number = keyboard.nextInt( ) ;

         System.out.println(number + " contains " + numberOfZeros(number) + " zeros.");
} // End of main


// * * * * Recursive Method * * * * 
public static int numberOfZeros(int n)  {
n = Math.abs(n); // Make sure the number is not negative. 

// 1. STOPPING CONDITION: Number has only only digit. 
if ( n < 10 )  {
    // if( n == 0 ) return 1;   else return 0;

    return n==0 ? 1:  0 ; // Conditional  operator.

} // end of the outer if block handling the stopping condition.


// 2. Else handle the case of two or more digits using recursion.
else {

    return n%10 == 0 ? 1 + numberOfZeros(n/10):  numberOfZeros(n/10) ; // Conditional  operator.


    // if (n%10 == 0) return 1 + numberOfZeros(n/10);
    // else return numberOfZeros(n/10);
} // end of outer else block 


} // end of recursive method method numberOfZeros. * * * * * * * * 


//  * * * * Non-recursive method using a while loop. * * * *

public static int numberOfZeros(int n)
{
if (n<0) n = -n;
if (n == 0) return 1; // Handle the special case of n = 0.


int zeros = 0; // The variable "zeros" will keep track of the number of zeros.
while (n > 0) { if(n%10==0) zeros++;   n = n/10; }
return zeros;
} // End of NON_RECURSIVE method numberOfZeros.

// End of multiline comment below. 
*/  

} // end of class
```

Comment: try something. you can't learn if you're not willing to experiment.

Comment: Where did you get this? Why do you post commented lines of code? I think the easiest solution is ```int numberOfDigits = String.valueOf(number).length();```

Answer (score 0):

`int noOfDigits = (int) Math.log10(n) + 1;`